# Jest unit test, how to solve async functions

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I got a component which looks like:

```
componentDidMount() {
    GetJobInfo(this.props.jobID)
        .then(forms=>this.setState({forms: getAllForm(forms)}))
        .catch(error=>console.warn(error))
}
```

How could I test this? I receive window is not defined error as GetJobInfo is async.

My test:

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {
    expect(shallow(<JobsTabSwitcher/>)).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Comment: How does your test look like?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: I assume `GetJobInfo` does a network request, in which case you need to mock it in your jest function.

Comment: So basically I have to pass the 'fetch', function as props and inject it?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html